# How to get a date for 2 days before today in LotusScript?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I'm doing an agent to send late in notification for 2 days before today with Sunday is a non-working day. Thus if today is Monday, agent will send late attendance for last Friday, if Tuesday, it will send last Saturday, if Wednesday, it will send Monday and etc. I already know how to get today's date. How do I get 2 days before today?

```
Dim tdy, dayToUse
Dim intl As NotesInternational
Set intl = ss.International
tdy=intl.Today
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following simple operation to get a specific date:

```
dayToUse = DateNumber( Year( Now ), Month( Now ), Day( Now ) - 2 )
```

You can also use the NotesDateTime object:

```
Dim dateTime As New NotesDateTime( "Today" )
Call dateTime.AdjustDay( -2 )
```

Hopefully this can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @Per Henrik Lausten's response:

In order to exclude Sunday, you can use the Weekday function.  It's a builtin function of the LotusScript language, not a method of the NotesDateTime class.  It takes a LotusScript date as its input, not a NotesDateTime.  So you might want to do something like this:

```
Dim dateTime As New NotesDateTime( "Today" )
Dim day as variant
dim adjustment as integer

day = CDat(dateTime.dateOnly)
if Weekday(day) = 2 or Weekday(day) = 3 then ' Monday or Tuesday
   adjustment = -3
else
   adjustment = -2 ' any other day 
end if

Call dateTime.AdjustDay( adjustment )
```

The above code has no special case for Today = Sunday.  It's unclear to me whether you can just ignore that case or do something special.